# Chaining multiple jquery events without callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, jquery-animate

I have an unknown number of events that I want to string together.  Basically, I'm getting them from a long array.  I'm using CoffeeScript and jquery.  Currently, I have:

```
function recursive(){
  if (arr.length>0)
     item = arr.shift()
     stander.animate({
        left: 100,
 },{
    duration: 100,
    complete: => @recursive
     })
}
```

But my stack trace is getting really long and confusing.  If I try and use a `while` loop all the array elements just go all at once.

```
while (arr.length>0 && previousAnimationEnded <- PSEUDO CODE)
     item = arr.shift()
     stander.animate({
        left: 100,
     },{
        duration: 100,
     })
}
```

This would prevent having such a long stack call.  My question is, does jQuery, js, or CoffeeScript a more sane way to link animation events besides callbacks?

Comment: You should be able to chain .animate() calls together and they'll get queued up to execute one after the other. See documentation example here: http://api.jquery.com/animate/#example-2

Comment: interesting.  i see they have xyz.animate().animate() on the same item.  I need to be able to do different animations on different items.  So example, animate a head, then when the head is done animating, animate the feet, then when feet done animating, animate the fingers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always use the underlying promise and pipe: http://jsfiddle.net/72YHh/3/ (click on the body once the animation has finished to restart it).

References:

- jQuery.fn.promise: http://api.jquery.com/promise/
- deferred.pipe: http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/

Comment: wow, that is excellent.  Thanks very much for knowing about both pipes and promises!  Very interesting!!

Comment: Even better, you can just call `$.when($elems)`, where `$elems` is a jQuery object containing all of the animated elements. This technique is covered in my book, *[Async JavaScript](http://leanpub.com/asyncjs).*

Answer (score 1):

I don't know CoffeeScript, but in JS, you can do it this way and you won't have a piling up stack trace.  The reason the stack doesn't pile up is because the animation is asynchronous so the call to `runArray()` and the call to `next()` finish immediately and only later when the animation finishes (via some sort of timer) is the completion function called thus invoking `next()` again.  So, though the code appears to be calling itself recursively, it isn't really and there is no accumulating stack frame.

```
function runArray(arr){

    function next() {
       if (arr.length > 0) {
          arr.shift().animate({left: 100}, 100, next);
       }
    }

    next();
}
```

In a simpler example, the stack frame doesn't accumulate here either:

```
var i = 0;

function go() {
    if (i++ < 1000) {
        item.innerHTML = i;   // any operation goes here
        setTimeout(go, 100);  // run this function again 100ms from now
    }
}
go();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delay the animation by a multiple of the array position:

```
$("div").each(function(i) {$(this).delay(i * 1000).animate({"left": "+=100"})});
```

you can see this in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Cp8JS/6/).